# clustering.. error with function "fviz_nbclust()"

Tags: cluster-analysis, factoextra

I'm trying to determine the number of cluters (elbow method and silhouette and gap statistic method) with function `fviz_nbclust`

knowing that at this point I'm only reproducing an example I found on Rpubs.com
thanks in advance for your help

I tried for all three methods ,
this

`fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss") + geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype = 2)+ labs(subtitle = "Elbow method")`

and this

`elbow_method <- fviz_nbclust(cust_data, FUNcluster = kmeans, method = "wss") elbow_method`

I keep getting this error message:
Error in call_with_cleanup(map_impl, environment(), .type, .progress,  :
object 'cleancall_call' not found